# COUNTIFS over multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make COUNTIFS go across two worksheets in the same excel file (Final Driver Forecast Model), just on different tabs. I need it to count if a driver returns between a certain time, then to put a 1 in that time slot. For example if a driver returns at 2:30 p.m. on the 27th, then the formula will put in a 1 in the July 27th slot from 2:00 p.m.-4:00 p.m. I have tried two different formulas the first is

`=COUNTIF3D(Bid Sheet '[1]Bid Sheet 1'!O4:O110,">="&B76,O4:O110,"<="&C76)`

This is looking at the worksheet called Bid Sheet 1 and the column O4 through O110 and deciding if the time fits in the time slot of B76 00:00 (12 a.m.) and C 76 2:00 a.m. The second formula I tried to do the exact same thing

`=COUNTIF3D(O4:O110,">="B76,O4:O110,"<="&C76,"FinalDriverForecastModel',Bid Sheet 1")`

Neither is working and they both give me #NAME? when I hit enter......What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure those are the formulas you're using? `=countif3d()` is not a formula, hence #NAME?

Comment: What is `COUNTIF3D`? That's not a built-in function (at least in Excel 2010) and will result in a `#NAME?` error.

Comment: Well on the internet it said that COUNTIF cannot be used to consolidate data in multiple worksheets and the only way to do so is to put 3D.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `COUNTIF.3d` function which is part of `Morefunc` add-in - but you'd need the add-in installed and it only allows you one condition and you appear to have two - try using 2 COUNTIFS functions added together.

`=COUNTIFS('Sheet 1'!O4:O110,">="&B76,'Sheet 1'!O4:O110,"<="&C76)+COUNTIFS('Sheet 2'!O4:O110,">="&B76,'Sheet 2'!O4:O110,"<="&C76)`

Comment: @Alison - To add to the `MoreFunc` caveat, it will also have to be installed on every computer that uses the worksheet. The add-in has some nice expanded functions but there are limitations when committing to their use.